# Merging GoogleService-Info.plist files for different services

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app that was created about 2 years ago. Since the beginning it has been using Google Analytics. I now want to add Firebase Cloud Messaging to it but when I download the new GoogleService-Info file from the firebase console I notice that things look very different. In particular the new file does not contain the `TRACKING_ID` that was in the old file. Also the `GOOGLE_APP_ID` is different.

This is what I get when downloading the file from developers.google.com:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>TRACKING_ID</key>
        <string>UA-1234567-16</string>
        <key>PLIST_VERSION</key>
        <string>1</string>
        <key>BUNDLE_ID</key>
        <string>en.myapp.app</string>
        <key>IS_ADS_ENABLED</key>
        <false/>
        <key>IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED</key>
        <true/>
        <key>IS_APPINVITE_ENABLED</key>
        <false/>
        <key>IS_GCM_ENABLED</key>
        <false/>
        <key>IS_SIGNIN_ENABLED</key>
        <false/>
        <key>GOOGLE_APP_ID</key>
        <string>1:123499115028:ios:12hvkyu2hv4uy</string>
        <key>PROJECT_ID</key>
        <string>myapp-ios</string>
    </dict>
```

This however is what I get when downloading it from the firebase console:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>AD_UNIT_ID_FOR_BANNER_TEST</key>
        <string>ca-app-pub-397764742544/2931234567</string>
        <key>AD_UNIT_ID_FOR_INTERSTITIAL_TEST</key>
        <string>ca-app-pub-12345674546672544/4411234567</string>
        <key>CLIENT_ID</key>
        <string>347330439762-c9m21gcjytcvvbjkn76v85li9kro1tf013.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
        <key>REVERSED_CLIENT_ID</key>
        <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.123456739762-c9m21nf395l5n1nwedqedqg445tf013</string>
        <key>API_KEY</key>
        <string>AIzaSyD5_khkgkujbjhygoijhjS_6DPPLU0PW2izsJ8</string>
        <key>GCM_SENDER_ID</key>
        <string>6398755452786</string>
        <key>PLIST_VERSION</key>
        <string>1</string>
        <key>BUNDLE_ID</key>
        <string>en.myapp.app</string>
        <key>PROJECT_ID</key>
        <string>myapp</string>
        <key>STORAGE_BUCKET</key>
        <string>myapp.appspot.com</string>
        <key>IS_ADS_ENABLED</key>
        <true/>
        <key>IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED</key>
        <false/>
        <key>IS_APPINVITE_ENABLED</key>
        <false/>
        <key>IS_GCM_ENABLED</key>
        <true/>
        <key>IS_SIGNIN_ENABLED</key>
        <true/>
        <key>GOOGLE_APP_ID</key>
        <string>1:123430439762:ios:12hvkyu2hv4uy</string>
        <key>DATABASE_URL</key>
        <string>https://myapp.firebaseio.com</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

How do I create a file that allows me to use both FCM and Google Analytics at the same time?

Comment: hi, what did you end up doing? I'm having exactly the same problem now

Answer (score 2):

We have previously had a similar issue, where we had been using Google Analytics for tracking analytics, and Firebase for our database.

After Firebase was merged into Google's products, we got in touch with [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/), as each project had it's own config file and we were unsure how to configure both services separately in our apps.

Their response was:

> Using a separate project for FCM only is a supported use-case as long as the correct Sender Id is defined in the Client implementation it should work.
>
> ...
>
> Important thing to remember for FCM setup is whichever project you choose to use please use the Sender ID and Server Key from the same project.

When asking for further details about how to set up the `Client implementation` in iOS, we were told:

> ...you need to change the value for authorizedEntity at  the FIRInstanceId class.
>
> In terms of Android, you can extend the basic Messaging and IID services if you would like to implement custom logics for receiving or handling notifications.

Does this help answer your question?

*I also recommend contacting Firebase Support for issues where you can't find the documentation for. They were a big help to us in merging with Google services.*